# How could I proof that there can not be equality in Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

For $k>0$.

I have gotten the expresion $F(\mu+\sigma k)-F(\mu-\sigma k) = 1-1/k^2$ for all $k>0$. I can not see why this equality is not possible for any continuous RV, what does this mean for the density $f$?

Comment: You will only have equality for $k \gt 1$ with a distribution with $P(X=\mu-c)=P(X=\mu+c)=\frac{1}{2k^2}$ and $P(X=\mu)=1-\frac{1}{k^2}$, which is a discrete distribution

Comment: Thanks you so much Henry, I needed some guide here, but why? is it because there are symmetry? When k=1, it would be 0, I can still not see why this can be possibe in a continuous RV

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(|X-\mu|\ge c)=a$ for some $0 \lt a\lt 1$ and $c\gt 0$.

Then $\sigma^2=E[(X-\mu)^2] = a E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\ge c]+(1-a)E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\lt c] $ and for a continuous distribution the right hand side must be strictly greater than $ac^2$ so $\sigma^2 \gt ac^2$. Let $k = \frac{c}{\sigma}$ implying $a \lt \frac{1}{k^2}$ and so using the original statement, for a continuous distribution  $$P(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\lt \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

There is a discrete distribution which gives equality, but it requires $E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\ge c]=c^2$ and $E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\lt c]=0$.  The first implies $P(|X-\mu|=c)=a$ and the second  $P(|X-\mu|=0)=1-a$ which combined with $E[X]=\mu$ means $P(X-\mu=-c)=P(X-\mu=c)=\frac{a}{2}$. This will give $\sigma^2=ac^2$ and with $k = \frac{c}{\sigma}$ gives $P(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)= \frac{1}{k^2}.$

Comment: his has been really helpful, I still have some questions, I really appreciate your help, Why for a continuous distribution must the right hand side  be strictly greater than $ac^2$ so $\sigma^2 \gt ac^2$ ? I was trying to prove this for a X~U[0,9], I got $\sigma^2 $=6.75 and if I set c=5 then P(X>=5)=0.5, so a=0.5 and $aC^2=12.5$ I can not see $\sigma^2 \gt ac^2$

Comment: what is the right hand side?

Comment: The right hand side is  $a E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\ge c]+(1-a)E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\lt c]$.  For example, a continuous distribution will not have $E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\lt c]=0$ which would require the conditional probability to be concentrated at a single point. Nor will it have $E[(X-\mu)^2\mid |X-\mu|\ge c]=c^2$ which would require the conditional probability to be concentrated at at most two points.